# Fields component media field using absolute url instead of relative

Tags: php, fields

I use the Fields component and I have a field "Media". You can choose an image this way. But this spits out a full  tag. This should be no problem but in my case I need it to be a full absolute url instead of relative. Does someone know how to achieve this or should I just use a regex to change the url myself?

Comment: 1. Fields can either be used via the automatic display or used manually in a template override. Which one are you talking about? 2. Why do you want your img's src attribute to have a domain in it?

Comment: 1. The problem is that when I use the media field it generates an <img src=..... tag.. 2. I want to output HTML and use that in another way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the rawvalue property of the field object

```
/* Rearrange Fields for use */
foreach($this->item->jcfields as $jcfield){
    $this->item->jcFields[$jcfield->name] = $jcfield;
}

$absolute_path_to_image = JUri::base() . $this->item->jcFields['your-field-name']->rawvalue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to override the core functionality. Or simply, in your template(s) where you output your images, you could just use:

```
<?php echo JUri::base() . $yourimagevariable;?>
```

Which will generate:

```
https://yourdomain.com/images/yourimage.jpg
```

Comment: Where can I find htis? I now use a regex...

Comment: @HuubS that entirely depends where and how you are using the image in your templates, if that is what you are doing. If you set your Field to `Automatic Display: Do not automatically display` then you can access it in your template instead, to produce the desired effect as per above. In an article layout, you would access the raw image path from the `$this->item->jcfields` object.

Comment: The problem is that the media field automatically  generates a full <img tag.. it's not only spitting out the url only.. I don't use automatic display, I always get the fields like this: $this->item->jcfields